# The dollar ($) prefixed field '$$$' in 'tracks.$$$' is not valid for storage

Tags: python, mongodb, backend

```
db.new_selen_top200.update_one({'name': stars['name']},{'$set': {'tracks': tracks } })
```

I am using this code to update a new element of a MongoDB document.

'tracks' is a dictionary that has the song title of an artist as the key and the lyric of the song as the value.

This worked on previous artists but it seems to give me this error "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$$$' in 'tracks.$$$' is not valid for storage" for a specific artist.

[image: This Is what 'tracks' looks like on the debugger]

This is what 'tracks' looks like on the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the track title starts with a dollar-sign, MongoDB is interpreting it as an operator.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the error message. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I've been looking but haven't been able to find an example. Could this field be a list for your use case?

Comment: I don't think a list would be effective because I want it to be saved as a key-value pair.